# Can I have a Untyped Collection in C#

Tags: c#, java, collections

I am porting some Java code to C# and I ran across this:

```
List<?>
```

As I understand it this is a `List` of type `Unknown`.  As a result I can dictate the type elsewhere (at runtime? I'm not sure).

What is the fundamental equivalent in C#?

Comment: The question is; is this really a good idea, or would you be better off with type safety?

Comment: List<Object> is not a relevant answer. if a method accepts List<?> parameter, it can accept all List types like List<String>, List<Integer>. If the parameter is List<Object>, it won't work.

Comment: It would be nice to have some context... where and what for this declaration is being used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best match to Java's `List<?>` would be C# 4.0 `IEnumerable<out T>` If you have a method that takes `List<?>` than you can call it with `List<Object>` and `List<String>` like so:

```
List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();
List<String> strList = new List<String>();

doSomething(objList); //OK
doSomething(strList); //OK

public void doSomething(List<?> theList) {
 ///Iterate through list
}
```

C# 4.0 `IEnumerable<T>` interface is actually `IEnumerable<out T>`, which means that if, say, `R` derives from `T`, `IEnumerable<T>` can be assigned to from `IEnumerable<R>`.

So, all you have to do is make your `doSomething` into `DoSomething` and have accept `IEnumerable<T>` parameter:

```
List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();
List<String> strList = new List<String>();

DoSomething(objList); //OK
DoSomething(strList); //OK

public void DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> theList) {
 ///Iterate through list
}
```

**EDIT:** If C# 4.0 is not available, you can always fall back to either untyped `IEnumerable` or `IList`.

Comment: C#4.0 uses declaration-site variance, whereas Java is use-site. Use-site makes more sense where "read-write" interfaces are common.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a list that can hold anything, you can use a `List<object>` or an `ArrayList`.

If you want a strongly-typed list that holds an unknown type, you should make a generic class or method and use a `List<T>`.

For more specific advice, please provide more detail.

Comment: List<T> is not an unknown type.  It is type T.  ? in java is something different.

Comment: @Serg: That's why I said **If**.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, as mentioned elsewhere, the **unbounded wildcard parameterized type is not the same as Object**.  Generics are not covariant.  So in the OP's Java example `List<?>` is not the same as `List<Object>`.  As an example,

```
// Unbounded wildcard type is not the same as Object...
List<?> unboundedList = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
unboundedList = objectList;    // no problems
objectList = unboundedList;    // whoops! compile time error
```

The only real use case for `List<?>` in Java is when interacting with legacy non generic collections.  It allows you to avoid [unchecked conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190772) warnings from the compiler.

C# does not have this use case.  C# generics were not implemented using erasure.  There is no backwards compatibility between the generic and non-generic collections in .net - they co-exist in the core .net libraries.  That is different from Java where the generic version of the collections api replaced the non generic version at JDK 1.5.

**So I don't think there is a reason to want this construct in C#**, and there is no direct equivalent that behaves in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `IList` is what you're looking for. It's a generic interface for lists, meaning you'll have to cast anything that comes out and be careful what you put in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the questioner wants to convert something like this

```
int size2(List<?> list)
{
    return 2*list.size(); 
}

List<Foo> list = ...
size2(list);
```

into C# equivalent.

The following code won't work, because it only accept `List<Object>`, not `List<Foo>`

```
int size2(List<Object> list)
{
    return 2*list.size(); 
}
```

Comment: In your scenario this is going to work:

int size2<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return 2*list.Count;
}

Answer (score -1):

You could just use

> `List<object>`

Comment: This does not work. `List<object>` is not equivalent to Java's `List<?>`, which is an implementation of contravariance, which C# 4 still does not support (only for interfaces and delegates)